# modal view in tab bar controller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In  my application i have a tab Bar controller. when i click a tab bar item a view is need to display (in small size) . i think it is acheived through modal view controller. Is there any other ways to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the UITabBarController and creating a complex situation. A tab Bar Controller is made for displaying a list of UIViewControllers, you shouldn't use it to display a UIView in small size.
You shouldn't display a modal View either after a click on a tab bar item.

Besides what you describe is contrary to Apple guidelines and might be cause of rejection of your app..

You can find informations on the "iOS Human Interface Guidelines", especially the chapter on the usage of the TabBar

> Don’t use a tab bar to give users
>   controls that act on elements in the
>   current mode or screen.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW29

Hope this helps,
Vincent